# Why aren't clang++ and g++ de-duplicating these instructions?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization, clang++, redundancy

Consider the following function:

```
std::string get_value(const bool b)
{
    if (b) {
        return "Hello";
    }
    else {
        return "World";
    }
}
```

g++ 11.0.1 20210312 compiles this (as C++17 and with maximum optimization) into:

```
get_value[abi:cxx11](bool):
        lea     rdx, [rdi+16]
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], rdx
        test    sil, sil
        je      .L2
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi+16], 1819043144
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdx+4], 111
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax+8], 5
        mov     BYTE PTR [rax+21], 0
        ret
.L2:
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi+16], 1819438935
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdx+4], 100
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax+8], 5
        mov     BYTE PTR [rax+21], 0
        ret
```

Why does it not move the two replicated `mov` instructions up before the jump, or even before the `test`, reducing the code size by two instructions?

The same thing happens with clang++ and libc++, except it only has one relevant instruction to move up.

(See this also on [<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/5dEb51))

Comment: Use `g++ -O3 -fverbose-asm -S example.cc` and look inside `example.s`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: That may offer a possible "excuse" for the mov-5, but not for the mov-0, which has the exact same instruction. Plus, at the end of the day - why does that matter? Should the code-size-reduction happen anyway?